# Meteor HTTP.get results in corrupt (?) content

Tags: http, meteor, server

On the server, I do:

```
var result = HTTP.get("https://spoticle001.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2NtoSkvYZeeetrf3k-0_thumb");
console.log("content length:", result.content.length);
```

I see 11781.  The header "content-length" field, however, indicates 12047, which is indeed the actual size of the file at this URL.

On the client, the same request results in yet another content length: 11618.

This seems to be the simplest possible use case of HTTP.get.  Why such strange results?

Answer (score 0):

That would be because `HTTP` is using `npm`'s `request` module to make requests and in it, by default, response encoding is set to `utf8`:

> `encoding` - encoding to be used on `setEncoding` of response data. If `null`, the `body` is returned as a `Buffer`. Anything else (**including the default value of `undefined`**) will be passed as the encoding parameter to `toString()` (meaning this is effectively `utf8` by default). (**Note:** if you expect binary data, you should set `encoding: null`.)

You can do that like this:

```
var result = HTTP.get("...", {
  npmRequestOptions: { encoding: null }
});
```

Testing:

```
result.content.length
> 12047
```

Useful information: [`request` options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestoptions-callback).